# In Web - Print a PDF without opening it in a browser

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I am building an application using LAMP. It contains a section for PDF reports. Currently the way it works is
      1. Click the button in web page named "pdf report"
      2. Pdf will open in browser 
      3. Use the print dialogue in the browser and click the print button to trigger print

I want it to be changed to 
      1. Click a button named "print pdf report"
      2. A printer dialogue box should appear and clicking print button should trigger the print

Is that possible to achieve it using php , fpdf or any other way in web ?

Comment: _Maybe_ open the PDF is an IFrame and call `.print()` on the iframe--but that's probably hacky at best. Unles the PDF plugins allows interop commands from the browser/javascript, you're looking at a hand-off to some extent.

Comment: This probably isn't possible, not with PDFs anyway.  Different browsers handle PDFs differently.  Some can open them directly, some use plugins, and (depending in people's setups) some open in their own programs.  One solution is not use a PDF.  Make an iframe with HTML/CSS and call `.print()` on that.  Otherwise, just open the PDF normally and let the user print it.  In our app, we solved it by just opening the PDF, and not trying to directly print it.

Comment: "2. Pdf will open in browser" This is only true if there some sort of plugin that displays the PDF inside the browser. For me (using Ubuntu) it is the default that a PDF will open in an external application. Why do you want to print something you never have seen?